# Why isn't this user banned and deleted?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to [this user](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/11344/i-hate-jehovahs-witness), whose username is certainly offensive, and whose only post (now deleted) was also offensive. I would have expected a ban and deletion of the account. Is this in process?

Comment: This is not this users first appearance. I destroyed a couple itterations already so you might have seen one of their older accounts in the past.

Answer (score 7):

What user? :) :) :)

Just FYI in the future, flag one of their posts if you can find one. Or snag one of the mods in chat, no need for a meta post on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Link is in the question. Their only (offensive) post was deleted. But point taken - I'll use chat in future.

Comment: @DJClayworth the "What user" was facetious, Part of my answer was destroying him

Comment: Oops. Next time I'll read the emoticons. :-(

Comment: Burn the heretic!!! err I mean offensive user... ;)